# Passing a function with callback and other arguments into another function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I want to use Promises to execute my tasks in synchronous order and for this, I have 3 following functions:

1. init(): My promise function to orchestre this;
2. saveUser(): function to save the user object into database;
3. main function that is responsible to run it in synchronous order.

It's working fine without pass the 'user' variable. I would like to know, how can I pass this 'user' variable into my `saveUser.bind()` to be run into my Promise and be saved by `userSave()` function?

```js
// promise function
function init(fn) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fn((err, result) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      console.log('the saveUser function ran inside my promise...');
      resolve(result);
    });
  });
}

// saveUser function, need receive the user variable and show in console log
function saveUser(callback, user) {
  console.log('1. the user will be save...', user);
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('2. the user was saved!');
    return callback(null, true);
  }, 1000);
}

// main function that I need to pass the user variable into saveUser() function
let user = {name: 'Rick'};
init(saveUser.bind(x => x)).
  then(() => console.log('3. Promise finished with success!')).
  catch((err) => console.log('3. Promise was rejected!', err));
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? what's your goal? because I have a gut feeling that you're overcomplicating your code...

Comment: Passing callback first is weird, the node convention is to have it as the last parameter. Have a look at [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) for many `init`-like functions then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if exactly how to organize the thing but below there's your snippet working

```js
// promise function
function init(fn, thisArg, ...params) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fn.apply(thisArg, [(err, res) => {
      console.log('the saveUser function ran inside my promise...');
    }, ...params]).then((data) => {
      resolve(data);
    }).catch((err) => {
      reject(err);
    });
  });
}

function saveUser(callback, user) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('1. saving...');
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('2. the user was saved! user name is ', user.name);
      resolve(callback(null, user));
      // reject('reason');
    }, 200);
  });
}

// main function that I need to pass the user variable into saveUser() function
let user = {name: 'Rick'};
init(saveUser, null, user).
  then(() => console.log('3. Promise finished with success!')).
  catch((err) => console.log('3. Promise was rejected!', err));
```

you could even save the first resolver/rejecter somewhere or pass them to `fn` when calling it if you don't want to create a new `Promise` for that.

Comment: Thanks FeMachine, but I need that promise return me the resolve() function to execute the following .then(). This works but resolve() not return. The console.log '3. Promise finished with success!' not appears

Answer (score 1):

The first param of bind is `this`.
The bind code will look like this. `saveUser.bind(x=>x, x=>x, user)`

```js
// promise function
function init(fn) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fn(resolve,reject);
  });
}

// saveUser function, need receive the user variable and show in console log
function saveUser(callback, user,resolve,reject) {
  console.log('1. the user will be save...', user);
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('2. the user was saved!');
    resolve(callback(null, true));
  }, 1000);
}

// main function that I need to pass the user variable into saveUser() function
let user = {name: 'Rick'};
init(saveUser.bind(this, x=>x, user)).
  then(() => console.log('3. Promise finished with success!')).
  catch((err) => console.log('3. Promise was rejected!', err));
```

Comment: ops, when I use 'this' in bind, the promise not return me the resolved() and not execute the following .then().

Comment: The console.log '3. Promise finished with success!' not appears

Comment: Updated, the problem was promise implementation

Answer (score 0):

```
init(cb => saveUser(cb, user))
```

Or

Change `saveUser(callback, user)` to `saveUser(user, callback)` and then

```
init(saveUser.bind(this, user))
```